# Contract constructor parameter which is also a contract

Tags: blockchain, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle-migration, binance

I have contract in solidity MasterChef.sol which can be seen at the link below https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-farm/tree/master/contracts
I want to deploy it using truffle on the Binance smart chain and the question is that the constructor of the MasterChef.sol takes in 5 args and two of them are contracts I want to know that how to pass the other two contracts i.e CakeToken.sol and SyrupBar.sol as the first two args in the deploy_contracts.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external type is address, so just pass contract addresses.

Hope it helps

Comment: if it is declared like "CakeToken public cake;" in the Masterchef contract then this means that I have to first deploy the CakeToken and then copy the address of this deployed contract and then pass it as the first arg in the constructor of MasterChef? I will be passing an address but the datatype is CakeToken how does that work? @Rob Hitchens

Comment: You are exactly right. It works because the ABI for CakeToken is defined in MasterChef or it won't compile. It only needs the address of an instance. It will not verify that the bytecode at the address passed in is indeed a CakeToken but obviously problems will surface when it tries to call non-existent functions if that is not the case. Think of it as a type cast conversion, address => CakeToken that is handled by MasterChef at runtime.

Comment: It is also acceptable to define the interface param as `address` and then go `CakeToken cakeToken = CakeToken(cakeTokenAddress);` which you can read "The instance of the CakeToken ABI (which is defined in this bytecode) at the given address". When you define the param as CakeToken you have already cast it as a contract but the _external_ encoding is still an address.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99776/weth-solidity-smart-contract-for-use-as-address-in-other-contract @Rob Hitchens